# How to Initialize array through object?

Tags: java

I want to make multiple object of DFA class and Initialize its field value by object through . I don't want to initialize array size. How I Initialize array field direct through object using {}.

when I Initialize like that in class its work fine.

```
  int[][] TT={{1,2},{2,1}};
```

but when I try to initilize like  that through object then its not work. 
Here my code.

```
public class DFA {

   int[][] TT;
   int IS;
   int[] FS;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    DFA fa1=new DFA();
    fa1.IS=0;
    fa1.FS={1};                        //Both FS and TT give error 
    fa1.TT={{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}};     

}
```

Comment: There is syntatic sugar at array declaration time, that you can't use any other time. You can do `fa1.TT=new int[][]{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}};`

Comment: you can use any Java Collection to do what you want, but the normal java array won't allow you to do so,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either

```
int[][] tt = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}};
fa.TT = tt;
```

or

```
fa1.TT = new int[][] {{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}};
```

I suggest using lowerCase for field names.

Answer (score 0):

> Array constants can only be used in initializers

So you either put it directly at the variables (`int[] FS = { 1 };`), or you do it with initializing the array first.

```
public class DFA {

    int[][] TT;
    int IS;
    int[] FS = { 1 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DFA fa1 = new DFA();
        fa1.IS = 0;
        int[] tmpFS = { 1 };
        fa1.FS = tmpFS;
        int[][] tmpTT = { { 1, 2 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 } };
        fa1.TT = tmpTT;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below syntax:

```
int[][] TT={{1,2},{2,1}};
```

is [Array Initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6) syntax. You can use it when you are declaring array. You can not separate array declaration and initializer syntax.

You should use `fa1.FS = new int[]{1};` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    public class DFA {

        int[][] TT;
        int IS;
        int[] FS;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            DFA fa1=new DFA();
            fa1.IS=0;
            fa1.FS=new int[]{1};                        //Both FS and TT give error
            fa1.TT= new int[][]{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}};

        }
 }
```